# PySpark: how to get all combinations of columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a DF with combinations of batches, inputs and outputs and I would like to be able to add their "unique combinations" back to the DataFrame. A simple representation of the data looks like this:

| Batch | Output | Input |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X |
| 1 | A | Y |
| 1 | A | Z |
| 2 | A | X |
| 2 | A | Y |
| 2 | A | Z |
| 3 | A | V |
| 3 | A | Y |
| 3 | A | Z |
| 4 | A | W |
| 4 | A | Y |
| 4 | A | Z |

So as you can see there are 4 batches and 3 different combinations of input to make the same output type, what I would like to end up with is:

| Batch | Output | Input | Combination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 1 |
| 1 | A | Y | 1 |
| 1 | A | Z | 1 |
| 2 | A | X | 1 |
| 2 | A | Y | 1 |
| 2 | A | Z | 1 |
| 3 | A | V | 2 |
| 3 | A | Y | 2 |
| 3 | A | Z | 2 |
| 4 | A | W | 3 |
| 4 | A | Y | 3 |
| 4 | A | Z | 3 |

I am looking to implement this in PySpark for further data manipulation, any guidance would be appreciated :)

EDIT: still inelegant but it works in PySpark! I am sure there must be a way easier method to do this using either sets or dictionaries, my brain just refuses to let me see it...

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1,'A','X'),
        (1,'A','Y'),
        (1,'A','Z'),
        (2,'A','X'),
        (2,'A','Y'),
        (2,'A','Z'),
        (3,'A','V'),
        (3,'A','Y'),
        (3,'A','Z'),
        (4,'A','W'),
        (4,'A','Y'),
        (4,'A','Z'),
        (5,'B','X'),
        (5,'B','Y'),
        (5,'B','Z')
    ],
    ["Batch", "Output", "Input"]
)

grouped = df.orderBy("Input").groupBy(["Batch", "Output"]).agg(f.concat_ws('_', f.sort_array(f.collect_list("Input"))).alias("Comb"))
grouped = grouped.withColumn("TotalComb", f.concat_ws('_',grouped.Output, grouped.Comb))
w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(f.col('TotalComb').asc())
groupunique = grouped[["totalComb"]].distinct().withColumn("UniqueComb", f.row_number().over(w))
connected = df.join(grouped, on = ["Batch", "Output"], how = "left").join(groupunique, on = ["totalComb"], how = "left")
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @Psychotechnopath I'm not sure even where to begin with this - I have given an example input and output no?

Comment: I'm going to be a bit anoying as well and not provide you with code that solves your issue, but I've got some hints. What I would do is to do a `groupBy` on the columns (Batch, Output and Input) and then a `count` for each combination. I would then `join` this back on the original DataFrame to create the `Combination`column, which would be the `count` from the `groupBy`. So, if I were you, I would start looking into `groupBy` on a dataframe and form there figure out how to get the `count` for each combination. If you run into issues, provide the code you've tried (you can update this question)

Comment: I don't think grouping by all 3 columns can work because it is the combination of the second two columns that are required. I have added a solution using pandas but it is not very tidy and I would like to implement this in PySpark. (I am aware that this solution would not work if the Output column was also varied, but it could be adapted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of inputs, classify by that list, find consecutive differences and use them create values to cummulatively sum over the entire df

```
w=Window.partitionBy("Batch","Output").orderBy("Batch")

df1=(df.withColumn('Combination',collect_set("Input").over(w))
     .withColumn('Combination',sum(when(lag('Output').over(Window.partitionBy("Combination",'Output').orderBy("Batch")).isNull(),1)
     .otherwise(0)).over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('Batch')))).show()

+-----+------+-----+-----------+
|Batch|Output|Input|Combination|
+-----+------+-----+-----------+
|    1|     A|    X|          1|
|    1|     A|    Y|          1|
|    1|     A|    Z|          1|
|    2|     A|    X|          1|
|    2|     A|    Y|          1|
|    2|     A|    Z|          1|
|    3|     A|    V|          2|
|    3|     A|    Y|          2|
|    3|     A|    Z|          2|
|    4|     A|    W|          3|
|    4|     A|    Y|          3|
|    4|     A|    Z|          3|
|    5|     B|    X|          4|
|    5|     B|    Y|          4|
|    5|     B|    Z|          4|
+-----+------+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. A follow up question - I see that your first withColumn (df.withColumn('Combination',collect_set("Input").over(w))...) is forcing the order of the Input into the combinations (e.g. no matter which order X Y Z is it will show (Z Y X) as the combination, what drives that ordering because from what I can see, w is ordered by Batch?